# How to make type inference work for instances adhering to nested generic interfaces?

Tags: generics, kotlin, interface, casting, type-inference

This minimal example

```kotlin
interface Foo<T> {
    fun foobinate(value: T)
}

interface Bar<T>

class AFoo<T> : Foo<T> {
    override fun foobinate(value: T) {}
}

class ABar<T> : Bar<T>

fun <T> doSomething(foo: Foo<Bar<T>>, x: Bar<T>) {
    foo.foobinate(x)
}

fun main() {
    val foo = AFoo<ABar<Int>>()
    doSomething(foo, ABar<Int>())
}
```

gives an error for the `doSomething` line:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is AFoo<ABar<Int>> but Foo<Bar<Int>> was expected
```

Is there any way to make it work, or is there some conceptual thing standing in the way?

Comment: Use `out` variance.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Where? `interface Foo<out T>` does not work. It results in `Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type T` on the line `fun foobinate(value: T)`. (Maybe I edited my question too late. I've added a member function.)

Comment: `fun <T : Bar<*>> doSomething(foo: Foo<T>, x: T) {
    foo.foobinate(x)
}`

Comment: @IR42 Thanks, it works. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `doSomething` like this should work

```
fun <A : Bar<*>> doSomething(foo: Foo<A>, x: A) {
    foo.foobinate(x)
}
```

This way, you ensure that x is of the specific type that `Foo` accepts, since both Foo and Bar have invariant type parameters.

This here doesn't work because the subclass of `Bar<T>` that becomes the `T` in `Foo<T>` gets and the subclass of `Bar<T>` of which `x` is an instance can be 2 different types.

```
fun <T, A : Bar<T>> doSomething(foo: Foo<Bar<T>>, x: Bar<T>) {
    foo.foobinate(x)
}
```